# How to compare table structure in two environments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've just inherited a fairly large DB, and been just informed that the table structure does not match between Dev and Prod. This is causing us problems since the code developed for Dev ends up crashing in Prod which is causing some pretty catastrophic releases.
So, I'd like to find a way to compare the tables, keys, and indexes programatically. Adding a tool requires client approval which is quite the challenge. I can't just copy the data over because they have different data sets.
Does anyone have any scripts that could help me figure out which ones to update?

Comment: Have you got Visual Studio? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=visual+studio+schema+compare&oq=Visual+Studio+schema+compare&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2560j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 for some links to how you can use it to compare schemas

Comment: If you have have Visual Studio you could use SSDT plugin and check the schema compare.

Comment: Meanwhile a bit worrying that your change control procedure allowed this to happen and, by the sound of it, more than one release to occur before it's fixed

Comment: If I were you, I would overwrite Dev with Prod and have your developers re-apply the changes they are working on.   All "artifact" changes will be gone.   What's more, I would do this on a regular basis.   We do it weekly here.   Saying you "can't do it because they have different data sets" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @yoelbenyossef Have you tried comparing using generating database script?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tools you could use. I prefer the Red Gate tool, however VS will work just as well.

Data is a non-sequitur, client approval is also a non-sequitur.

Simply script out the two tables, add them to your local client or a test server, use the tool to compare the two.

To expand on Tab Alleman's response it is typically SOP to roll Prod down to Dev. You can find tons of information on SDLC via bing / google.

A secondary option would be to rename the Dev version of the table, script out and "move" the table from Prod to Dev. Insert the data from the Dev version of the table back into the new table which will have the proper object name.

Answer (score 0):

> **Perhaps simplest way without using any gimmicky third party tools is provided in the SQL Server Management studio it self**.

**Below are brief steps to give overall idea of actions involved:**

- **STEP 1:** Generate full database script for both the Dev and Prod databases using SQL Server Management Studio's inbuilt Generate a Script option.
- **STEP 2:** Compare both the scripts using any basic text comparison utility (like Beyond compare, meld, WinMerge etc).
- **STEP 3:** Note down differences and make plan to fix them.

---

*and If you are still reading* :)

**More detailed explanation of generating database script:**

1. In Object Explorer, expand **Databases**, right-click a database, point to **Tasks**, and then click **Generate Scripts**. Follow the steps in the wizard to script the database objects.
2. On the **Choose Objects** page, select **Script entire database and all database objects**.
3. On the Set Scripting Options page, select Save scripts to a specific location.
4. To specify advanced scripting options, select the Advanced button in the Save scripts to a specific location section.
5. ***Tricky step*** - In **Advanced Scripting Options** popup Select **False** for **Include Descriptive Headers**.

   [image]

   *This will remove unwanted time stamps, which is a great help while comparing scripts.*
6. On the **Summary** page, review your selections. Click **Next** to generate a script of the objects you selected.